# Making a batch file for multiple CMDs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Lets say I have 2 services I want to start and a property file.

```
 -svc1.cmd
 -svc2.bat
 -svc2prop.properties
```

Lets have directories as C:\program1\bin\  and C:\program2\bin\  + C:\program2\config\

then I tried to do it like this:

```
start cmd /k call C:\program1\bin\svc1.cmd
start cmd /k cd C:\program2\ .\bin\svc2.bat .\config\svc2prop.properties
```

I can start them both separately by opening a local CMD. The thing is, if I am in the directory C:\program2\ I can open up a local CMD and run this statement without problems " .\bin\svc2.bat .\config\svc2prop.properties"

But I want to create a batch file that:  first, opens a new cmd and starts the svc1.cmd, then opens another cmd in which it goes to C:\program2\ and runs the "" .\bin\svc2.bat .\config\svc2prop.properties" " statement ... but for some reason it doesnt work.

Any possible solution ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you use a call in the first line?

Comment: no idea i guess i left it there but it works without it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the second line should use `/D` option to start the process in the required directory:

```
start /D C:\program2 cmd /k .\bin\svc2.bat .\config\svc2prop.properties
```

(in your example, you were just passing a lot of arguments to an useless `cd` command)

If you have some current directory problems with the first line, just do the same:

```
start /D C:\program1\bin cmd /k call svc1.cmd
```

Comment: Amazing, this seems to work, but now i have a problem. the thing im doing is starting up Zookeper and then i want kafka. but now they start at the same time so sometimes kafka starts up faster than zookeper binds and thats a problem, now i need to delay the other CMD to start by etc 5sec. i tried "Sleep 5" - in a batch file this should be a sleep for 5 sec but then the other line does not execute at all ... why ?

Comment: `sleep 5` only works if MSYS/Cygwin is installed. I would recommend the native command `timeout /T 5` that does roughly the same.