# Batch file to run local Angular2 and Django servers

Tags: django, batch-file, angular

I have a Django Angular2 project. I'm trying to create a batch file to make it easy to run my local django server and NPM.

- How can I open a new console in Batch? For example I want to open a console and simply run the command `python myproject/manage.py runserver`. And then I want to open another console and run the command `npm start`.
- How can I run `npm start` in another directory? For example; the batch file is in `./` and I want it to start in `./angular2-project`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a batch file for multiple CMDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633293/making-a-batch-file-for-multiple-cmds)

Comment: In case `npm` is a batch file on its own, consider to use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)...